# Ripple colour has already been defined Android

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to import a library in Android:

```
compile 'com.materialcontentoverflow:materialcontentoverflow:1.1.0'
```

But when I try it tells me that:

```
 C:\Users\A\Desktop\Project\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\me.drakeet.materialdialog\library\1.2.2\res\values\values.xml
```

But if I look in that project there is no values with rippleColor. This is the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<!-- From: file:/Users/drakeet/AndroidStudioProjects/MaterialDialog/library/src/main/res/values/color.xml -->
<eat-comment/>
<color name="card_background">#ffffff</color>
<color name="card_shadow">#10000000</color>
<color name="lite_blue">#ff359ff2</color>
<color name="window_background">#00000000</color>
<!-- From: file:/Users/drakeet/AndroidStudioProjects/MaterialDialog/library/src/main/res/values/dimens.xml -->
<eat-comment/>
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
<!-- From: file:/Users/drakeet/AndroidStudioProjects/MaterialDialog/library/src/main/res/values/strings.xml -->
<eat-comment/>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="app_name">MaterialDialog</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
```

The library that I am trying to import has the following as values.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<!-- From: file:/home/artur/workspaceAndroidStudio/MaterialContentOverflow/materialcontentoverflow/src/main/res/values/colors.xml -->
<eat-comment/>
<color name="shadow_end_color">@android:color/transparent</color>
<color name="shadow_mid_color">#14000000</color>
<color name="shadow_start_color">#44000000</color>
<declare-styleable name="FloatingActionButton"><attr name="android:background"/><attr name="backgroundTint"/><attr name="backgroundTintMode"/><attr format="color|reference" name="rippleColor"/><attr name="fabSize"><enum name="normal" value="0"/><enum name="mini" value="1"/></attr><attr name="elevation"/><attr format="dimension|reference" name="pressedTranslationZ"/></declare-styleable>
<declare-styleable name="MaterialContentOverflow"><attr format="reference" name="buttonDrawable"/><attr format="reference" name="fabButtonColor"/><attr format="reference" name="contentColor"/><attr format="enum" name="buttonPosition"><enum name="left" value="0"/><enum name="center" value="1"/><enum name="right" value="2"/></attr></declare-styleable>
<!-- From: file:/home/artur/workspaceAndroidStudio/MaterialContentOverflow/materialcontentoverflow/src/main/res/values/dimens.xml -->
<eat-comment/>
<dimen name="fab_content_size">24dp</dimen>
<dimen name="fab_elevation">8dp</dimen>
<dimen name="fab_size_mini">40dp</dimen>
<dimen name="fab_size_normal">56dp</dimen>
<dimen name="fab_translation_z_pressed">6dp</dimen>
```

I can't work out what the problem is?! Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

Checking the [source on github](https://github.com/arturgaleno/MaterialContentOverflow/blob/master/materialcontentoverflow/src/main/res/values/attrs.xml#L22)

```
   <!-- Ripple color for the FAB. -->
    <attr name="rippleColor" format="color|reference" />
```

This library is using the `rippleColor`.

You can't use it since it is used by supportlibrary.
 You can clone the library changing **the attr**.

Comment: Thank you, how do I do this?

Comment: Even a link to a tutorial or guide would be really helpful, not even sure what to Google?

Comment: hi any further advice?

Comment: @SuperBale You have to clone the library locally and change it. I don't know other ways

Comment: I'm not sure what that means? Sorry if I'm being ignorant, English isnt my first language. Will I need GitHub?

Comment: You need to clone the project locally. You can't change the attr otherwise. The only alternative is to open a issue on github project and ask the author to add a prefix in his project attributes.